# WPF from DynamicResource to StaticResource

Tags: wpf, dynamicresource, staticresource

I had been working on a WPF project for a while, but haven't touched it in 2 months now.
Now that I'm back on it, I have the following problem:

I use merged dictionaries to create skins, and easily swap them at runtime. 
However, each skin does not change at runtime. But while I was noobish at this, I just followed a bunch of tutorials, and I used DynamicResource everywhere, not even wondering if I should rather use StaticResource.

The result is that when I tried sending my app to a friend using windows XP (i use seven). The Luna theme is thrown over my app, making the design ugly...
And as far as I understood it comes from DynamicResource.

So now, I want to change to StaticResource, I simply tried to replace every "DynamicResource" with "StaticResource". And it throws me this exception:

```
Message = "'La valeur fournie sur 'System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension' a levé une exception.' numéro de ligne '8' et position de ligne '230'."

In english, it means: Message = "'The value given to 'System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension' threw an exception.' line number '8' and position on the line '230'.
```

I then put a try/catch block to have a better idea of the problem:

```
{"Impossible de trouver la ressource nommée'styleBackground'. Les noms de ressources respectent la casse."}
```

In english: `Impossible to find the resource named 'styleBackground'. The resource names are case sensitive.`

It's about a TabItem.

So two questions here: 
Am I doing the right thing by changing DynamicResource to StaticResource?
And if so, what do I need to do?

Thanks,

FB.

EDIT: the program gets the error on the last of these lines:

```
<Window x:Class="Sc2ReplayMonkey.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:scm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Sc2ReplayMonkey" ResizeMode="CanResize"
        Title="Starcraft II Replay Monkey"
        Width="991" Icon="Resources\Icons\SC2_Replay_Monkey.png"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" d:DesignHeight="1024" Height="774" Visibility="Visible" Foreground="#00000000" Margin="0">
```

Comment: WPF is not good at outputting errors. If using Visual Studio, try displaying the output window. It should give you more information about the problem.

Comment: I'm affraid it's not helping me much, it outputs:
`'Sc2ReplayMonkey.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib'Sc2ReplayMonkey.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xaml.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_fr_b77a5c561934e089\System.Xaml.resources.dll'
'Sc2ReplayMonkey.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\mscorlib.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_fr_b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.resources.dll'
`

Comment: I found my mistake, when switching to StaticResource, the application needs to load every Resource when it starts, and i was loading only the base dictionary, no skins.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer so other users can benefit :)

Comment: The solution was to load the base ResourceDictionary + a skin ResourceDictionary at startup.
Basically if you work with staticresource, you need to have one of each x:key loaded at all times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to load all resourcedictionaries at startup instead of starting with no skin (which works with dynamic resource) and letting the user chose a skin at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

What do you make thinking that the problems comes from DynamicResource ?

As far as I know, DynamiResource, as opposed to StaticResource, is just used to fetch the resource at runtime, rather than at compile time. DynamicResource is useful in cases where you have to reference the resource before it is declared (that will raise a compilation error if you used StaticResource).

```
<ResourceDictionary><DataTemplate>... <Rectangle Fill={DynamicResource MyBrush}></Rectangle>  ...</DataTemplate> <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyBrush"></SolidColorBrush> <ResourceDictionary>
```

In this case, using StaticResource instead of DynamicResource will raise a compilation error.

Now, about your problem, if you do not assign styles explicitly to your controls, WPF will pick default style from the current OS theme, XP theme in your case. To solve this, you can pick-up Win 7 theme then embed it with your app.

That adds a lot more work for you but this is the only way to redefine all control styles such that it keeps those styles, no matter the OS on which it is executed.

HTH

Riana